# How to automate rsync in linux?

Tags: cron, ubuntu-16.04, rsync

I want to run rsync(in remote linux system) automatically in every minute. so whatever the changes (in test.txt, as mentioned below) are done in one system, it should be affected in another system at the same minute interval.

For this purpose, I have changed in `sudo crontab -e` , and added

```
*/1 * * * * /home/john/rsync.sh
```

`rsync.sh` contains two commands:

```
sudo rsync -av /home/john1/test.txt remote@remote_ip:
sudo rsync -av --update /home/john1/test.txt remote@remote_ip:
```

when I am running `rsync.sh` manually, all the changes are affected successfully.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to run rsync automatically in some specific time interval(say, in every 1 minute)? The task is loaded in rsync.sh script.

Comment: I'm still not following. Is the above approach not working for you, does it throw errors, what are the errors? Or are you searching for alternative ways of doing this?

Comment: In essence, I would remove the `sudo` from the script. Do an `ssh` keyexchange to prevent passwords and this should work.

Comment: Also, why would you first `rsync` the file over and then do a second `rsync` of the same file with an `update` flag. This seems very confusing and I'm wondering about its purpose.

Comment: Yeah, You can provide alternate ways too. the above approach is not working for me.The sh script is not running automatically in specified time interval.

Comment: Did you have a look at the errors? You say this is a cron run as root. Just type `mail` and have a look what it says. And then provide all the information you have to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you added this in the root crontab, you don't need to start the rsync commands with `sudo`.

Things that run in crontab will probably not have the same environment variables. You can add the absolute path to rsync if you're unsure, for example `/usr/bin/rsync`. Also check other environment variables, for example running `set`.

When you run it manually, you're already in a specific shell which is probably able to run it. But when cron runs it, it doesn't know which interpreter to use. Always start your scripts with `#!/usr/bin/bash` (or whatever is your favorite shell). And/or call your cron job specifying which shell to use, for example:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /home/john/rsync.sh
```

I hope this helps. ;)